# Insert a range of numbers from a call to sp_sequence_get_range

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sequence, cross-apply, number-table

Given the following code:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE dbo.NextTestId AS [bigint]
 START WITH 10 INCREMENT BY 2 NO CACHE 
GO

DECLARE  
  @variableNumberOfIdsNeeded INT = 7, -- This will change for each call
  @FirstSeqNum SQL_VARIANT , @LastSeqNum sql_variant, @SeqIncr sql_variant;  

EXEC sys.sp_sequence_get_range @sequence_name = N'dbo.NextTestId', 
            @range_size = @variableNumberOfIdsNeeded, 
            @range_first_value = @FirstSeqNum OUTPUT, 
            @range_last_value = @LastSeqNum OUTPUT, 
            @sequence_increment = @SeqIncr OUTPUT;

-- The following statement returns the output values
SELECT @FirstSeqNum AS FirstVal, @LastSeqNum AS LastVal, @SeqIncr AS SeqIncrement;
```

I get a result like this:

```
FirstVal    LastVal    SeqIncrement 
-------     -------    -------------- 
38          50         2
```

I would like to have a **set based** way to take these results and insert each value (skipping by SeqIncrement) into this table:

```
DECLARE @newIds TABLE (IdType VARCHAR(100), [NewId] BIGINT)
```

So when I am done, a `SELECT * from @newIds` would return:

```
IdType    NewId
-------   -------
TestId    38
TestId    40
TestId    42
TestId    44
TestId    46
TestId    48
TestId    50
```

NOTE: I don't want to use a loop if possible.  Also, I will need to get a variable amount of results (this one shows 7, but it will change each call).

I think there may be a cross apply or some such thing that can do this.  But I can't seem to figure it.

Comment: Do you mean you want a set-based way that *avoids* the call to `sp_sequence_get_range`, or in addition to?

Comment: @AaronBertrand - I mean that after the call to `sp_sequence_get_range`, I want a set based way to insert 38 - 50 (every other) into a table.  So no, I don't want to avoid the call to `sp_sequence_get_range`. (I updated my question to be a bit more clear on this.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should be good up to about 2,500 values (depending on version):

```
;WITH x(n) AS 
(
  SELECT TOP (@variableNumberOfIdsNeeded)
    (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY number)-1) 
    * CONVERT(BIGINT, @SeqIncr)
    + CONVERT(BIGINT, @FirstSeqNum)
  FROM master.dbo.spt_values
  ORDER BY number
)
--INSERT @newIds([NewId]) 
SELECT n FROM x;
```

If you need more, or are worried about using the view `master.dbo.spt_values`, see other possible techniques for generating sets without looping here:

- [Generate a set or sequence without loops – part 1](http://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-1)
- [Generate a set or sequence without loops – part 2](http://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-2)
- [Generate a set or sequence without loops – part 3](http://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-3)

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you!  What is `master.dbo.spt_values`?  Looks like a system table.  Are you just using it because it has a lot of rows?  Is it safe to use a system table like this?

Comment: Yes, it's a system table (well, technically it's a view), should be relatively safe, but you can instead use things like `sys.all_objects` in your local database. Or create your own numbers table, as I advocate in those articles.

Comment: I like the number table option.  Thank you again for the great answer!